# Regex trim all <br>'s on a string while ignoring line breaks and spaces

Tags: regex

```
var str = `
  <br><br/>
  <Br>
  foobar
  <span>yay</span>
  <br><br>
  catmouse
  <br>
`;

//this doesn't work but what I have so far
str.replace(/^(<br\s*\/?>)*|(<br\s*\/?>)*$/ig, '');

var desiredOutput = `
  foobar
  <span>yay</span>
  <br><br>
  catmouse
`;
```

I want to ensure that I remove all `<br>`'s regardless of case or ending slash being present. And I want to keep any `<br>`'s that reside in the middle of the text. There may be other html tags present.

Edit: I want to note that this will be happening server-side so DOMParser won't be available to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may try using the following pattern:

```
^\s*(<br\/?>\s*)*|(<br\/?>\s*)*\s*$
```

This pattern targets `<br>` tags (and their variants) only if they occur at the start or end of the string, possibly preceded/proceeded by some whitespace.

```js
var str = '<br><br/>\n<Br>\nfoobar\n<span>yay</span>\n<br><br>\ncatmouse\n<br>';
console.log(str + '\n');

str = str.replace(/^\s*(<br\/?>\s*)*|(<br\/?>\s*)*\s*$/ig, '');
console.log(str);
```

Note that in general parsing HTML with regex is not advisable.  But in this case, since you just want to remove flat non-nested break tags from the start and end, regex might be viable.

Comment: You could also write it the same as `^(\s*<br\/?>)+|(<br\/?>\s*)+$`

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a regular expression for this - regular expressions and HTML parsing don't work that well together. Even if it's *possible* with a regex, I'd recommend using `DOMParser` instead; transform the text into a document, and iterate through the first and last nodes, removing them while their `tagName` is `BR` (and removing empty text nodes too, if they exist):

```js
var str = `
  <br><br/>
  <Br>
  foobar
  <span>yay</span>
  <br><br>
  catmouse
  <br>
`;

const body = new DOMParser().parseFromString(str.trim(), 'text/html').body;
const nodes = [...body.childNodes];

let node;
while (node = nodes.shift(), node.tagName === 'BR') {
  node.remove();
  const next = nodes[0];
  if (next.nodeType === 3 && next.textContent.trim() === '') nodes.shift().remove();
}

while (node = nodes.pop(), node.tagName === 'BR') {
  node.remove();
  const next = nodes[nodes.length - 1];
  if (next.nodeType === 3 && next.textContent.trim() === '') nodes.pop().remove();
}
console.log(body.innerHTML);
```

Note that it gets a lot easier if you don't have to worry about empty text nodes, or if you don't care about whether there are empty text nodes or not in HTML output.

Comment: This was my first approach and generally good advice but in my specific case I am doing this server side.

Comment: You are right but this is not HTML parsing. It's removing a known static string from a line both ends.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
/^(\s*<br\s*\/?>)*|(<br\s*\/?>\s*)*$/ig
```

Comment: You don't need `[Bb]` etc. because you have the case insensitive `i` flag set.